# How to build an WHERE clause with IF statement with value OR IS NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems to be tricky to use the WHERE clause if you want to filter on an attribute value that is a value or is NULL.

This is for Retool (a dynamic MySQL environment). I've tried to split it up in different AND clauses but it seems to be harder than it looks because a value needs an equation,  and IS NULL doesn't.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE filter = IF({{checkbox1.value}} = TRUE,0,1 OR IS NULL) 
ORDER BY order DESC
```

What I need a query that delivers a list based on the state of the checkbox:

If checkbox = true, I want to select records where the filter value is 0

If checkbox = false, I want to select records where the filter value is 1 or null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you check to be null, I guess you mean `filter`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 
  ({{checkbox1.value}} AND filter = 0) 
  OR 
  ((NOT {{checkbox1.value}}) AND coalesce(filter, 1) = 1))
ORDER BY order DESC
```

Comment: What I need a query that delivers a list based on the state of the checkbox:

If checkbox = true, I want to select records where the filter value is 0
If checkbox = false, I want to select records where the filter value is 1 or null

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  You can just use `OR`:

```
WHERE (filter = {{checkbox1.value}} OR {{checkbox1.value}} IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL , IF statements in query works like this

IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)

whereas 2nd and 3rd parameter is optional and first one is mandatory .

So answer might be

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE filter = IF({{checkbox1.value}} = TRUE,0,1) AND IS NULL 
ORDER BY order DESC

Answer (score 0):

> If checkbox = true, I want to select records where the filter value is
>   0
>
> If checkbox = false, I want to select records where the filter value
>   is 1 or null

Almost literally translated in code:

```
WHERE
  CASE 
    WHEN {{checkbox1.value}} = TRUE  THEN filter = 0
    WHEN {{checkbox1.value}} = FALSE THEN filter = 1 OR filter IS NULL
  END
```

That can be shortened to

```
WHERE
  CASE {{checkbox1.value}}
    WHEN TRUE  THEN filter = 0
    WHEN FALSE THEN COALESCE(filter, 1) = 1
  END
```

But since in MySQL `TRUE` and `FALSE` are just aliases for `1` and `0`, you can also express the same logic with

```
WHERE COALESCE(filter, 1) = (NOT {{checkbox1.value}})
```

or

```
WHERE COALESCE(filter, 1) = (1 - {{checkbox1.value}})
```